# How do I open AVD Manager in Visual Studio 2019 C++ mobile application?

Tags: android, visual-c++, mobile, emulation

I try to run an app and it says to use AVD manager. Where is the AVD Manager and how do I open it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the toolbar. See the image
[image]